# Can't select a vertex group in this hook modifier

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups

I have this silly problem. See image. I want to stretch this cylinder with the right icosphere. I selected the vertices on the right end of the cylinder and added them to a vertex group with weight 1. Then on the right icosphere I add a hook modifier, I select the cylinder as object, and the vertex group list is empty. But the vertex group is there, but it doesn't show up, I can't select it in the hook modifier. How to make it show?

[image]

Aha, I put the hook modifier on the cylinder, not the icosphere. This works, though the vertex group is pulled to the top of the sphere, instead of the center, where the origin is. How to pull it to the center of the icosphere?

Also, is there a way to preserve the relative distance between the pulled vertices, so the end cap of the cylinder is pulled but not deformed.

[image]

Comment: It is working the opposite way: set the hook modifier on the cylinder, not on the sphere

Comment: All is on top of the sphere, because either the sphere or the cylinder is rotated: so apply rotation for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook modifier have to be set on the hooked object not on the hooker (well... not totally sure this is the good term in English).

[image]

Concerning the stretch on top of the sphere: this is due to a rotation.

The hook is influenced by all objects transformations. So these transformations needs to be coherent at the moment the hook modifier is set.

[image]